# Decode a url and store to a string with special characters

Tags: c#, urldecode

In one of my programs I have to process an encrypted Url. I want to save the parameter to a string and I want to keep the special characters as they are

```
string input_url ="domain.com/auth?token=%2FhKjSuSAO6ctIrgokvB9hmHJPlHQXqTmpuH9fEPWp8w";
```

I want to process the token query string in a decoded form 
I tried the code

```
string input_url ="domain.com/auth?token=%2FhKjSuSAO6ctIrgokvB9hmHJPlHQXqTmpuH9fEPWp8w";    
val = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(input_url.ToString());
val2 = val.Split('=')[1];
```

But I get the value as `%2FhKjSuSAO6ctIrgokvB9hmHJPlHQXqTmpuH9fEPWp8w`

What i want is `val=/hKjSuSAO6ctIrgokvB9hmHJPlHQXqTmpuH9fEPWp8w` (keep `%2F` as `/`, like for  other special characters if any exists)

How can I do this?

Comment: but its %2F in the input, do you want to transform that into /? Because you said its / in the beginning

Comment: in example special character is at beggining. It might be in the middle as well like token=ssAdf%2FghiJK. Now what i want is ssAdf/ghiJK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode works with .Net 4 Client profiles only
 string value_string = Uri.UnescapeDataString(e.Url.Query); wil work for .net 4 applications

Answer (score 7):

You're using the wrong decoder; this is a URL, not HTML, so try `UrlDecode`:

```
  string input_url ="domain.com/auth?token=%2FhKjSuSAO6ctIrgokvB9hmHJPlHQXqTmpuH9fEPWp8w";    
  val = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(input_url);
  val2 = val.Split('=')[1];
```

This gives the result in `val2` of:

```
  /hKjSuSAO6ctIrgokvB9hmHJPlHQXqTmpuH9fEPWp8w
```

`HTMLDecode` is designed for HTML entites such as `&amp;`.

Comment: I am using it in a .Net 4 WPF app. and System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode is not available there

Comment: im pretty sure it is, just add the dependency

Comment: System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode works  with .Net 4 Client profiles only :( 
string value_string = Uri.UnescapeDataString(e.Url.Query); works for me . Some one suggests that some problems with spaces decoding.
and Uri.UnescapeDataString is suggested as answer for the problem